# Count non-empty fields mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to count how many fields of a specific fieldset are empty in mysql, I've found some examples but they all go through the whole table.

Basically I have 8 fields,

listing_photo_1 to listing_photo_8, I want to get the count of how many of them are filled.

I tried:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from listings 
                       WHERE listing_photo_1 IS NOT NULL AND 
                             listing_photo_2 IS NOT NULL AND 
                             listing_photo_3 IS NOT NULL AND 
                             listing_photo_4 IS NOT NULL AND 
                             listing_photo_5 IS NOT NULL AND 
                             listing_photo_6 IS NOT NULL AND 
                             listing_photo_7 IS NOT NULL AND 
                             listing_photo_8 IS NOT NULL AND 
                             pmpid = '$pmpid'");

$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $data['total'];
```

Which results in: `1`

To clarify the result I am expecting:

listing_photo_1: filled

listing_photo_2: filled

listing_photo_3: filled

listing_photo_4: empty

listing_photo_5: empty

listing_photo_6: empty

listing_photo_7: empty

listing_photo_8: empty`

The result should be `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code attempts to count the number of rows where all the fields a not null.  You should be using `is not null` rather than just `not null`.

To count the number of fields, use this:

```
SELECT sum((listing_photo_1 IS NOT NULL) +
           (listing_photo_2 IS NOT NULL) +
           (listing_photo_3 IS NOT NULL) +
           (listing_photo_4 IS NOT NULL) +
           (listing_photo_5 IS NOT NULL) +
           (listing_photo_6 IS NOT NULL) +
           (listing_photo_7 IS NOT NULL) +
           (listing_photo_8 IS NOT NULL)
          ) as total
from listings
WHERE pmpid = '$pmpid';
```

To count the number of rows:

```
SELECT count(*) as total
from listings
WHERE listing_photo_1 IS NOT NULL AND
      listing_photo_2 IS NOT NULL AND 
      listing_photo_3 IS NOT NULL AND 
      listing_photo_4 IS NOT NULL AND 
      listing_photo_5 IS NOT NULL AND 
      listing_photo_6 IS NOT NULL AND 
      listing_photo_7 IS NOT NULL AND 
      listing_photo_8 IS NOT NULL AND 
      pmpid = '$pmpid'";
```

EDIT:

If they are blank, use logic like this:

```
SELECT sum((listing_photo_1 IS NOT NULL and listing_photo_1 <> '') +
           (listing_photo_2 IS NOT NULL and listing_photo_2 <> '') +
           (listing_photo_3 IS NOT NULL and listing_photo_3 <> '') +
           (listing_photo_4 IS NOT NULL and listing_photo_4 <> '') +
           (listing_photo_5 IS NOT NULL and listing_photo_5 <> '') +
           (listing_photo_6 IS NOT NULL and listing_photo_6 <> '') +
           (listing_photo_7 IS NOT NULL and listing_photo_7 <> '') +
           (listing_photo_8 IS NOT NULL and listing_photo_8 <> '')
          ) as total
from listings
WHERE pmpid = '$pmpid';
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I'm getting closer, using the first example you've provided. Although it does now show `8` but only `3` fields are filled in my database.

Comment: @MariusProllak . . . Are the unfilled values `NULL` or more like `''`?  What is the type of those fields?

Comment: Oh guess that's the problem then ? They are indeed `''` type is `varchar`

Comment: Awesome, thank you the last solution you provided works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE listing_photo_1 IS NOT NULL AND listing_photo_2 IS NOT NULL....
```

**Edit:**

If you need to get individual not null count of each columns, you can do like

```
SELECT count(listing_photo_1),count(listing_photo_2),....count(listing_photo_8) 
from listings where pmpid = id
```

`Count(column)` will count not null values only.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting a result now, but it's not what I expected, please see edited question for clarification on what I'm trying to achieve.