# change div position base by mysql output

Tags: mysql, css, html

I have this contact book that I'm doing. I've saved each contact information in a mysql database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `officemail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `homemail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `officestreet` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `homestreet` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `picture` longblob NOT NULL,
  `img` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `homephone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `officephone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;
```

Now my problem is: Lets say that many of these column are empty (see image below) [only two columns are filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLEcN.png)
[image]

How do I change the ***red marked*** position based on how many column are filled? Is this even possible?

**EDIT** 
Here is my display code

```
while($contactRow = $contact->fetch_assoc()){
                $random = rand(0,1000006050);
                $emptyImage = (empty($contactRow['picture'])) ? '<div class="emptyProfile" style="cursor: pointer;width: 95px"><label for="file-input'.$contactRow['id'].'" style="z-index:2;zoom: 1;display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;"><img src="images/person.jpg" style="width: 95px;cursor: pointer;z-index:2;zoom: 1"><div style="position: absolute;margin-top:-25px;font-size: 8pt;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;zoom:0;opacity: 0;text-align: center;width:95px;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);height:21px;cursor: pointer;z-index:1;" class="uploadContactPicture" id="uploadContactPicture'.$contactRow['id'].'"><div style="margin-top: 3px;" id="uploadContactPictureText'.$contactRow['id'].'">Upload photo </div></div></label> <input id="file-input'.$contactRow['id'].'" class="'.$contactRow['id'].'" type="file" name="file[]" style="display: none;" accept="image/*"/></div>' : '<div style="background-image:url(php/imageViewContact.php?id='.$contactRow['id'].'&rand='.$random.');box-shadow:-3px 3px rgba(128, 123, 123, 0.28);width:95px; height: 95px;background-size:cover;background-position:center top;vertical-align:middle" class="fullProfileContact" id="'.$contactRow['id'].'"></div>';
                $contactRowStreet = (empty($contactRow['homestreet'])) ? (empty($contactRow['officestreet']) ? '' : $contactRow['officestreet']) : $contactRow['homestreet'];
                ?>
                <div style="background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.64);width:97.5%;border-radius: 5px;box-shadow:1px 3px rgba(128, 123, 123, 0.28);margin-bottom:9px;height:124px;" id="contact<?php echo $contactRow['id']; ?>">
                    <div class="imageHolderContacts" style="border-right: 1px dotted rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.57);width:115px;float: left;">
                        <img src="images/tape.png" style="width:50px;position: absolute;z-index:999;margin-top: -19px;margin-left:22px;" alt="tape"><?php echo $emptyImage; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left;margin-left: 16px;margin-top:3px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 11pt;color:rgba(103, 103, 103, 0.65);">
                        <div style="position: absolute; width:99%;display:inline-table;">
                            <div style="float: left;margin-right:4px;">
                                <?php echo ucfirst($contactRow['name']).' '.ucfirst($contactRow['surname']); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:290px;border-left: 1px dotted #999999;">
                                <div style="margin-left:4px; width:400px;position:static"><?php echo $contactRowStreet ?> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on you where you want to locate your data. But from your question I think that you want to manage your data somewhere in center-vertically with contact's image.

If you are able to [count the non empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18675124/1039706) in your mysql row then you can manage it with php if/switch statement.

**Note: Please follow the relevant stackoverflow answer to count the non empty fields of your mysql table rows**

```
<?php

$margin-top = "";
  switch ($row['total_non_empty_fields']) {
      case 1:
          $margin-top = "100px";
          break;
      case 2:
          $margin-top = "90px";
          break;
      case 3:
          $margin-top = "80px";
          break;
      case 4:
          $margin-top = "70px";
          break;
      case 5:
          $margin-top = "60px";
          break;
      case 6:
          $margin-top = "50px";
          break;
      case 7:
          $margin-top = "40px";
          break;
      case 8:
          $margin-top = "30px";
          break;
      case 9:
          $margin-top = "20px";
          break;
      case 10:
          $margin-top = "10px";
          break;
      default:
          $margin-top = "0px";
          break;
      }

  echo "<div id='contact-detail' style='margin-top:".$margin-top."'>
            your code......
       </div>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Arijanit Nitti Salihu,

As we have not your code for display data i am assume and answer you this:

If you get empty field value you can simply put a blank space for that like `"&nbsp;"`  So your code something like

```
if(!empty($row['name'])){
  echo $row['name'];
}else{
 echo "&nbsp;"
}
```

If you want top margin in place of that element, you can place style `min-width` and `clear:both;` property: OR you can use `<p></p>` tag so it would be something like :

```
if(!empty($row['name'])){
      echo "<p>".$row['name']."</p>";
    }else{
     echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>"
    }
```

As per your give code i am showing code for `name` and `surname` field, in same way you have to do with all other field.

```
while($contactRow = $contact->fetch_assoc()){
                $random = rand(0,1000006050);
                $emptyImage = (empty($contactRow['picture'])) ? '<div class="emptyProfile" style="cursor: pointer;width: 95px"><label for="file-input'.$contactRow['id'].'" style="z-index:2;zoom: 1;display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;"><img src="images/person.jpg" style="width: 95px;cursor: pointer;z-index:2;zoom: 1"><div style="position: absolute;margin-top:-25px;font-size: 8pt;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;zoom:0;opacity: 0;text-align: center;width:95px;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);height:21px;cursor: pointer;z-index:1;" class="uploadContactPicture" id="uploadContactPicture'.$contactRow['id'].'"><div style="margin-top: 3px;" id="uploadContactPictureText'.$contactRow['id'].'">Upload photo </div></div></label> <input id="file-input'.$contactRow['id'].'" class="'.$contactRow['id'].'" type="file" name="file[]" style="display: none;" accept="image/*"/></div>' : '<div style="background-image:url(php/imageViewContact.php?id='.$contactRow['id'].'&rand='.$random.');box-shadow:-3px 3px rgba(128, 123, 123, 0.28);width:95px; height: 95px;background-size:cover;background-position:center top;vertical-align:middle" class="fullProfileContact" id="'.$contactRow['id'].'"></div>';
                $contactRowStreet = (empty($contactRow['homestreet'])) ? (empty($contactRow['officestreet']) ? '' : $contactRow['officestreet']) : $contactRow['homestreet'];
                ?>
                <div style="background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.64);width:97.5%;border-radius: 5px;box-shadow:1px 3px rgba(128, 123, 123, 0.28);margin-bottom:9px;height:124px;" id="contact<?php echo $contactRow['id']; ?>">
                    <div class="imageHolderContacts" style="border-right: 1px dotted rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.57);width:115px;float: left;">
                        <img src="images/tape.png" style="width:50px;position: absolute;z-index:999;margin-top: -19px;margin-left:22px;" alt="tape"><?php echo $emptyImage; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left;margin-left: 16px;margin-top:3px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 11pt;color:rgba(103, 103, 103, 0.65);">
                        <div style="position: absolute; width:99%;display:inline-table;">
                            <?php if(!empty($contactRow['name'])){ ?>
                            <div style="float: left;margin-right:4px; clear:both;">
                                <p><?php echo ucfirst($contactRow['name']).' '.ucfirst($contactRow['surname']); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <?php }else{ ?>
                                 <div style="float: left;margin-right:4px; clear:both;">
                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if(!empty($contactRow['surname'])){ ?>
                            <div style="float: left;margin-right:4px; clear:both;">
                                <p><?php echo ucfirst($contactRow['surname']).' '.ucfirst($contactRow['surname']); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <?php }else{ ?>
                                 <div style="float: left;margin-right:4px; clear:both;">
                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <div style="overflow:hidden;width:290px;border-left: 1px dotted #999999;">
                                <div style="margin-left:4px; width:400px;position:static"><?php echo $contactRowStreet ?> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
```

I hope this will help you.!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't think you understand me. I want more like `margin-top`

Comment: I have updated my question and input my display code. Why I've done this is because I've no clue on how to do this!