# How to count multiple columns with mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am facing a problem I am not capable to solve on my own. There a several questions out that regarding counting but I did no see one where the counting is done like I would need it. In my table I have three slots that can be booked by a Person, represented by their ID, like this:

```
ID | Slot1 | Slot2 | Slot3
1    45      53
2    1       27       6
3    53
4    6       45
5    15      53
```

It is possible that slots are free but it is not possible that an ID blocks to slots.

Now I would like to count how often each ID used on of the three slots. The result would look like this for the table above:

```
ID Count
1  1
6  2
15 1
27 1
45 2
53 3
```

Is that possible with one mysql statement or do I need to GROUP BY for each slot and add the slots up later in my script?

If it is possible to do the counting in mysql over all three slots, would it also be possible to join the result with a second table that holds the names to the IDs?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: Not sure, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675069/count-non-empty-fields-mysql) might be something for you..

Comment: `multiple` is a pleonasm because rows is a plural, title doesn't make sense in your question. We need examples to clarify your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a `union all` and aggregation:

```
select slot, count(*)
from ((select slot1 as slot from t
      ) union all
      (select slot2 as slot from t
      ) union all
      (select slot3 as slot from t
      )
     ) s
where slot is not null
group by slot
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Could I also add a JOIN LEFT here to get the names to the IDs? I added a WHERE after the t since I not only have numbers but also some text in my slots apparently.

Comment: @Sikarjan . . . I'm not sure what your comment refers to.  The above should work with strings as well as numbers.

Comment: It does but I only want IDs so I modified the where clause to WHERE slot > 0 but I am more interested if I could combine that with a JION to get the name to the ID from a second table.

Comment: Okay got it. After s: LEFT JOIN table2 ON s.slot = table2.id

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` :

```
SELECT s.SLOT_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT slot1 as slot_id FROM YourTable 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT slot2 FROM YourTable 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT slot3 FROM YourTable ) s
GROUP BY s.slot_id
```